# MongoDB Auth Fails to find username on Bitnami MEAN Stack Image

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, bitnami

Trying to run a web app (MEAN) on Amazon EC2 Instance but am encountering the following problem. Can anyone help me with this?

```
node app.js The Server has started on 9091
/opt/bitnami/apps/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:128
    username = username.replace('=', "=3D").replace(',', '=2C');
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at executeScram (/opt/bitnami/apps/SomeApp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:128:24)
    at /opt/bitnami/apps/SomeApp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:277:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: Same issue for me.. Did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 4):

Mongoose can do auth in 2 ways:

1, Connection string:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port(usually 27017)/db')`

Where username and password are the respective username and password for that specific db, host would be the host where your db is hosted (so localhost or some domain/IP), port is the port mongo listens on, and db is the name of the db you want to connect to

2, Using options. From the docs:

`var options = {
  useMongoClinet: true,
  auth: {authdb: 'admin'},
  user: 'myUsername',
  pass: 'myPassword',
}
mongoose.connect(uri, options);`

I also faced the 'username undefined' error in the first approach, but I succeeded in the second approach.

[Reference] https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4891